# Ubuntu Archive API?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to query the Ubuntu archive on a machine that doesn't have python-apt installed (and for reasons beyond my control *can't* have python-apt installed). Is there an API endpoint for packages.ubuntu.com or a similar service which I can query to find out:

1. Is there a package?
2. If so, basic attributes like summary, version, series?

Answer (score 2):

The [Launchpad API](https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/1.0.html) has an [archive object](https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/1.0.html#archive) which you can probably use to query for packages. If the machine has `python-launchpadlib` installed, it will be much easier to do, though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! `python-launchpadlib` is installed so I'll try this route out

Comment: This is a great way to check if the package exists in the archive, but I can't get the packages summary which is what I'm most after. Any other alternatives?

Comment: I suppose you may have to grab the Packages.gz and parse it to get more information such as description and dependencies.